# Чтобы сделать то-то, набери … или … и затем …

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Пишу технический текст, а точнее, инструкцию.

Там есть фрагменты наподобие следующего:

> Чтобы сделать то-то, набери `gg` или `1G` и затем `=G`.

Идея здесь в том, что `gg` и `1G` по своему действию одинаковы, но независимо от того, какая из этих двух команд будет набрана, за нею должна последовать команда `=G`.

Как здесь расставить запятые? Интуитивно, я бы расставил так:

> Чтобы сделать то-то, набери `gg` или `1G`, и затем `=G`.

Но я не уверен, что это грамотно с точки зрения правил пунктуации русского языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Сказуемое-то (*набери*) общее, как и опущенное подлежащее (*ты*):
*Чтобы сделать то-то, (ты) набери `gg` или `1G` и затем `=G`.* || Союз И продолжает простое предложение.
Можно использовать другой союз:
*Чтобы сделать то-то, (ты) набери `gg` или `1G`, а затем `=G`.*

*Набери* — это разговорный вариант, если значение — "напечатай". Лучше так: *введите*.